# Error when running Azure csrun on an offline Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: .net, azure, windows-server-2012-r2, .net-4.6.1

I ran into an issue when trying to execute csrun on an offline Windows Server 2012 R2.

I have installed the offline update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK, as well as Azure SDK (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51657), and also localDB and IISExpress 10. I have not installed any instance of Visual Studio.

The Azure Compute and Storage Emulators are running. I try to start a project I uploaded to the Server 2012 R2 with the Azure Command Prompt. Therefore I move to the project folder in the Command Prompt, where the csx file is located and execute the following command:

```
csrun csx\debug ServiceConfiguration.local.cscfg /useiisexpress
```

There follwing errors are thrown:

```
Error : .NET Framework v4.6.1 is requested by the application but is not found on this computer.
Error : .NET Framework v4.6.1 is requested by the application but is not found on this computer.
Error : .NET Framework v4.6.1 is requested by the application but is not found on this computer.
Error when creating deployment. Exception details: Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabricException: The system is missing a prerequisite to execute the service. ---> Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabricException: Please see the release notes.
```

After that error, I have downloaded a program, checking what .NET Versions are installed. It shows, as expected, that Version 4.6.1 is installed on the Server. Here's a screenshot of the Versions:
[.NetVerions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRcQk.png)

I hope you can help me fix this error.

Best regards,
David

Comment: please try to restart the server and run same command to check if same issue appears.

Comment: Restarting the server did not help. The same problem is still remaining.

Comment: Try to run ``dir %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v* /O:-N /B`` from command prompt to detect which .NET Framework version is installed.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this problem and the solution is to upgrade the version of the Compute Emulator installed on the machine. Even if the right .NET Framework version is installed on the machine, the emulator has to be new enough to use it. You can download the latest version of the emulator [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54917).